# How to hash with salt then unhash in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, salt

I have this asp.net project that I need to hash the password (preferably with salt) and save it in sql database then unhash it for comparing with the login password or sth like that....
the thing is I'm not sure what is the best way to do it in a most secure way and how can I code this in C#?

Comment: Your approach is incorrect, and the ability to "unhash" a hash would make hashing completely redundant. All you need to do is hash the password into the database (look into SHA / HMAC SHA) when an account is created, and then whenever a user attempts to log in, hash their password attempt in exactly the same way, and test the hash against the hash that is stored in the database...simple!

Comment: this is not a duplicate question ...in that link the answer was incomplete for me as it won't suggest a code and it just suggests to hash()...I know I should use hashing but I was searching for the best method with the use of salt, this is so important to know the method like sha256 or md5...people please read the question thoroughly before voting this is not fair to vote down someone because you think you need vote up for your own question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not unhash. That's the point of hashing: it cannot be reversed.

You look up the salt, then you hash the password that they entered together with the salt. If the hash is the same as the hash in the database, it's a valid login.

Maybe take a look here:
[Salted password hashing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right)

Comment: the link suggest using RNGCryptoServiceProvider class however I find the example code in msdn a little bit confusing..how exactly should I use it here?

Comment: I think they only use it to create a random byte[], then convert that byte[] to a string. First, you instantiate a byte[]: byte[] salt = new byte[24]; Then you fill it with random values: RNGCryptoServiceProvider csprng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider(); csprng.GetBytes(salt);

Answer (score 3):

First of all `you cannot recover the hashed data`. Its `one way process`. But you can match hashed data. To do so check the code given below :

Do this inside your button click event

```
string salt = GetSalt(10); // 10 is the size of Salt 
string hashedPass = HashPassword(salt, Password.Text);
```

This are the functions that will help your to hash the password

```
const string alphanumeric = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";

     public static string GetSalt(int saltSize)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder("");

                while ((saltSize--) > 0)
                    strB.Append(alphanumeric[(int)(r.NextDouble() * alphanumeric.Length)]);
                return strB.ToString();
            }

    public static string HashPassword(string salt, string password)
            {
                string mergedPass = string.Concat(salt, password);
                return EncryptUsingMD5(mergedPass);
            }

    public static string EncryptUsingMD5(string inputStr)
            {
                using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
                {
                    // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
                    byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputStr));

                    // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
                    // and create a string.
                    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
                    // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));

                    // Return the hexadecimal string.
                    return sBuilder.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Similarly, when you try to match the password to authenticate the user, perform the same method just fetch your hashed password from your database and compare them. If the entered hashed password matches the database hashed password, its an authorized user.

**Updated :**

> 1. When you hash the password of the user for the first time and then store into database in the same table store the salt for that user.
> 2. Next time when you try to compare the password, fetch that salt of the user from the database and hash it using to compare with the
>      hashed password in the database.

Hope that answers your Question.

Comment: tnx for the answer...but from the code I see that the salt is random every time so what happens when I want to compare the passwords?...wouldn't it give me another encrypted password?...shall I save the salt too?

Comment: and could u explain a little about alphanumeric?

Comment: alphanumeric string is nothing but a collection of Alphabets and digits used to create dynamic salt. for example it will generate salt like "2R9GmSZzth" for hashing

Comment: check my updated answer. for your first Question on how to match if the salt is randomly generated.

Comment: @sara.y You store both the salt and the hash in the database. One salt for each user. And you shouldn't use MD5. It is obsolete and no longer considered secure.

Comment: @Dennis_E, if we cannot unhash a hashed code, than how MD5 is not considered to be secure anymore?

Comment: Just google for 'md5 no longer secure'. It is vulnerable and can be cracked. I don't exactly understand the details...

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Even I will get rid of this MD5 hashing.